# Create Pdf from UICollectionView full content?

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, pdf-generation, uicollectionview

I need to create a **PDF** from **UICollectionView full content**. I am currently able to create a pdf from UICollectionView Visible part. Please, help me i want to display whole content of collection view.

Comment: facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. (Swift 3.x)

```
    class PdfTools {

    func generatePdfFromCollectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView?, filename:String, success:(String) -> ()) {

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()

        let contentArea = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: collectionView.contentSize.width,
            height: collectionView.contentSize.height
        )

        collectionView.frame = contentArea

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, contentArea, nil)

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        collectionView.drawHierarchy(in: collectionView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

        if let filepath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
            let fileFullPath = filepath + "/" + filename

            if pdfData.write(toFile: fileFullPath, atomically: true) {
                success(fileFullPath)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you use it.

```
    let pdfTool = PdfTool()   
    pdfTool.generatePdfFromCollectionView(self.collectionView, filename: "myFancy.pdf") { (filename) in 
// use your pdf here 
}
```

Comment: This solution doesnt work if I have collection view with large number of item. In my case I have more than 30 items and each collectionView item has an image view. Blank page PDF is created in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work fro multiple pages content view. It only resizes 1st page to very very long height like 375x16,000